# Automatic refresh a div tag when something inserted into a database

Tags: php, ajax, database

I created a PHP page that select from the database `names` and created html page that contains Javascript code to refresh a div tag from the php page every 5 seconds automatic here s the code

```
<script>
function Ajax(){
var xmlHttp;
    try{    
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    }
    catch (e){
        try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e){
                alert("No AJAX!?");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
        setTimeout('Ajax()',1);
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET","select.php",true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

window.onload=function(){
   setTimeout('Ajax()',2000);
}
</script>
<div id="ReloadThis"></div>
```

so this is awesome, but I need to refresh only when something new inserted in to the database.
So is there is a way to do that?

Comment: How will the browser be aware of an update? You should start by looking at either long polling the server or periodically connecting and asking if there are updates.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there is no way to do this without polling in plain JavaScript / HTML / PHP. A solution without polling would require that the server is able to communicate with the client. But as soon as the server sent everything the client needs, the server can't even know if the client is still there.

Comment: Load names with timestamp of the newest 'name' inserted in DB. Then every X seconds ask server if there is any new name in DB - do not forget to send that timestamp you loaded before. If there is a newer name, send it to browser - with new timestamp as well. Overwrite timestamp with current one and. And let it repeat.

Answer (score 3):

One way I think that could be achieved is by PUSH notifications. So that you keep an active connection to the DB and this tells you when a modification was made.

This is also known as "long polling" or "comet programming". (Check this resource out: [comet programming](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg28/index.html)). I have personally not worked with the technology so I don't know its limitations ( I heard about problems on browser support).

I guess however a dirty way to do it would be:

1. When you store a new value in your DB also update a page with json values (or whatever you wish) and let's say a unique ID number
2. Use your ajax every X second and check the value of the ID on that page, if new update your values and if not just sleep.

This could work but it would be checking on regular intervals and not when a change happened.

Answer (score 1):

Use should use Comet (e.g. AJAX + **Long Polling**)

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use a javascript library (like jQuery), where you can find function like "setTimeout" that do your goal very well.
This is an example:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

@hint Hmmmm... May you should try http://jquery.com/?

For example you should send last inserted id:

HTML:

```
<div id="user-list">
    <div class="user-block" data-id="1">User #1</div>
    <div class="user-block" data-id="2">User #2</div>
    <div class="user-block" data-id="3">User #3</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var lastID = 0;

$(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var callback = function(response) {
            // TODO: for (var i = 0; i < ....)
            $('#user-list').append('<div class="user-block" data-id="' + reponse[i].id + '">' + response[i].name + '</div>');

            lastID = respose[i].id;
        };

        $.post(url, {"id" : lastID}, callback, "json")
    }, 5000);
});
```

PHP:

```
$lastID = $_POST['lastID']; // TODO: security
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id > :id"; // TODO: :id => $lastID
// DO QUERY
echo json_encode($data); // $data = result of query
```